# Accept string only if not all are special characters

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that can be used to detect if the user has entered only special characters.

If the user enters `!@#`, it should be rejected but if the user enters `test !@#`, it should be allowed.

I have tried using `^[^\W]+$` but it selects only when there is a text without any special character. If I enter `test ^&^&%^`, it does not select it.

Comment: What are all these 'special' characters? Is input allowed if any other character than those that you define as 'special' is used? Or, is it allowed if (as per your example) alphachars has been used at least once?

Comment: all special characters are included in this. But the issue is that when I have only special character, it should not be allowed. however, if there is a normal text alongwith special characters, it should be allowed. and that is my requirement. Hence if mods are asking to close the ticket, atleast guide me to right question where such condition can be handled.

Comment: Right, so something like `^(?![!@#]+$).*` should work? You can change the character class to include more characters but the idea here is that you won't allow it to be only those characters in that specified class. I see the answer from Niel is build around the same concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a negative look ahead `(?!...)` to only capture if the string is not purely special characters.

```
^(?![\W_]*\Z).*$
```

Or:

```
^(?![\W_]*$).*$
```

Or another approach without the negative look ahead is to check if at least one character is a word character:

```
^.*[a-zA-Z\d].*$
```

[image]

Where:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?![\W_]*\Z)` - Match the next part only if it is not purely special characters up to the end of the string.
- `.*` - Match any character
- `$` - End of string

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without using a lookahead, you can match at least a word character. Note that \W can also match a newline.

```php
 ^\W*\w.*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\W*` Optionally match non word chars
- `\w` Match al least a single word char
- `.*` Optionally match any char except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lr5OkY/1)

If you consider `_` a special char, you can add it to the first character class, and also add it to the second negates character class to exclude it:

```php
^[\W_]*[^\W_].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tu3AaW/1)

Comment: Yes that is also a good solution and I will keep this in mind. but my current scenario is limited to a single line input text box where I do not have to take care of new line.

Comment: @ganeshpandhere Then the pattern can be even shorter `^\W*\w.*$`

Comment: If `_` is considered special, then it will look like `^[\W_]*[^\W_].*$`. If all connector punctuation class should be subtracted: ``^[\W\p{Pc}]*[^\W\p{Pc}].*$``. Or, with multiple line support: `(?s)^[\W_]*[^\W_].*$`.